# Return value from list based on value being between 2 other list elements

Tags: python

I have a project I am working on that requires me to place items in predefined price tiers based on the value being pulled from an excel file. I have everything else worked out in my script except this last piece.

What I want to be able to do is build a list of lists (not stuck on the data structure if there is a better/more efficient option), check to see if the value is between `i[0]` and `i[1]` and return `i[2]`.

Example would be:

```
my_value = 22.99
[[0],[24.99],['0-24.99'],[25,49.99,'25-49.99]......]
```

Desired output: `'0-24.99'`

Edit:

Now that I am back to my computer, I've written out the code to try and pull this off.

These functions are used for a calculation and to match the tier.

```
    #define functions
    #calculate Eligible Average Selling Price
    def asp(x,y):
        if float(y)==0:
           return 0
        else:
           return float(x)/float(y)
    #Search Tiers Dictionary and return undefined if tier does not exist
    def inTier(x,y,z):
        for t in Tiers[x]:
            if float(t[0]) <= asp(y,z) <= float(t[1]):
                return t[2]
            else:
                return 'Tier Undefined'
```

Here is the dictionary I am looping through to match the tier.

```
    Tiers= {'Desktop':[[0, 24.99, '0-24.99'],[25, 49.99, '25-49.99'],[50, 74.99, '50-74.99'],[75, 99.99, '75-99.99'],[100, 124.99, '100-124.99'],[125, 149.99, '125-149.99'],[150, 199.99, '150-199.99'],[200, 249.99, '200-249.99'],[250, 299.99, '250-299.99'],[300, 499.99, '300-499.99'],[500, 749.99, '500-749.99'],[750, 999.99, '750-999.99'],[1000, 1999.99, '1000-1999.99'],[2000, 2999.99, '2000-2999.99'],[3000, 9999.99, '3000-9999.99']],'Chair':[[0, 24.99, '0-24.99'],[25, 49.99, '25-49.99'],[50, 74.99, '50-74.99'],[75, 99.99, '75-99.99'],[100, 124.99, '100-124.99'],[125, 149.99, '125-149.99'],[150, 199.99, '150-199.99'],[200, 249.99, '200-249.99'],[250, 299.99, '250-299.99'],[300, 499.99, '300-499.99'],[500, 749.99, '500-749.99'],[750, 999.99, '750-999.99'],[1000, 1999.99, '1000-1999.99'],[2000, 2999.99, '2000-2999.99'],[3000, 9999.99, '3000-9999.99']],'Gear':[[0, 9.99, '0-9.99'],[10, 24.99, '10-24.99'],[25, 49.99, '25-49.99'],[50, 74.99, '50-74.99'],[75, 99.99, '75-99.99'],[100, 124.99, '100-124.99'],[125, 149.99, '125-149.99'],[150, 199.99, '150-199.99'],[200, 249.99, '200-249.99'],[250, 299.99, '250-299.99'],[300, 349.99, '300-349.99'],[350, 399.99, '350-399.99'],[400, 499.99, '400-499.99'],[500, 749.99, '500-749.99'],[750, 999.99, '750-999.99'],[1000, 1999.99, '1000-1999.99'],[2000, 2999.99, '2000-2999.99'],[3000, 9999.99, '3000-9999.99']],'Laptop':[[0, 49.99, '0-49.99'],[50, 99.99, '50-99.99'],[100, 149.99, '100-149.99'],[150, 199.99, '150-199.99'],[200, 249.99, '200-249.99'],[250, 299.99, '250-299.99'],[300, 349.99, '300-349.99'],[350, 399.99, '350-399.99'],[400, 449.99, '400-449.99'],[450, 549.99, '450-549.99'],[550, 649.99, '550-649.99'],[650, 749.99, '650-749.99'],[750, 999.99, '750-999.99'],[1000, 4999.99, '1000-1999.99'],[2000, 6999.99, '2000-6999.99']],'Printer':[[0, 24.99, '0-24.99'],[25, 49.99, '25-49.99'],[50, 74.99, '50-74.99'],[75, 99.99, '75-99.99'],[100, 124.99, '100-124.99'],[125, 149.99, '125-149.99'],[150, 199.99, '150-199.99'],[200, 249.99, '200-249.99'],[250, 299.99, '250-299.99'],[300, 499.99, '300-499.99'],[500, 749.99, '500-749.99'],[750, 999.99, '750-999.99'],[1000, 1999.99, '1000-1999.99'],[2000, 2999.99, '2000-2999.99'],[3000, 9999.99, '3000-9999.99']],'Tablet':[[0, 49.99, '0-49.99'],[50, 99.99, '50-99.99'],[100, 149.99, '100-149.99'],[150, 199.99, '150-199.99'],[200, 249.99, '200-249.99'],[250, 299.99, '250-299.99'],[300, 349.99, '300-349.99'],[350, 399.99, '350-399.99'],[400, 449.99, '400-449.99'],[450, 549.99, '450-549.99'],[550, 649.99, '550-649.99'],[650, 749.99, '650-749.99'],[750, 999.99, '750-999.99'],[1000, 1999.99, '1000-1999.99'],[2000, 4999.99, '2000-4999.99']]}
```

And here is where values are being evaluated from a list row into a list row

```
    row=[row[0],row[1].split(" ")[1],row[2].split(" ")[1],int(re.findall(r'\d+', row[3])[0]),row[4],row[5],row[6],asp(row[5],row[6]),inTier(row[0],row[5],row[6])]
```

and an example row that is returning 'Tier Undefined':

```
    ['Gear', 'REGION 27 SOUTHEAST', 'DISTRICT 7 E ATL', 'LOGANVILLE GA (6852)', 'WNDA3100 RANGEMAX', '32.99', '1']
```

In general it seems like the only tiers that gets a positive match are the first in the list of lists Dictionary value.

Comment: Why are the first 3 in separate sub-array, but the next group is in a single sub-array?

Comment: `if i[0] <= my_value <= i[1]: return i[2]`

Comment: @Barmar lack of clarity on my part. In looping it would start as something like for i in tiers:

Comment: @Barmar using this as part of a loop through the list of lists?

Comment: No, I meant why is it `[0],[24.99],['0-24.99']` for the first tier, but `[25,49.99,'25-49.99]` for the second tier.

Comment: @Barmar Oh. Sorry, the list starting with 25 is the correct syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your list has a typo, and you meant to write:

```
tiers = [[0,24.99,'0-24.99'],[25,49.99,'25-49.99]......]
```

Then you just loop through them:

```
for tier in tiers:
    if tier[0] <= my_value <= tier[1]:
        selected_tier = tier[2]
        break
```

Comment: Got it. If I need to cycle through a potential batch of 500,000 values, would this be the best way to approach?

Comment: Are all the tiers ranges of 25 like these examples? If they are, you can just divide.

Comment: No. They will vary

Comment: Then I don't think there's any better way. Put the most common tiers at the beginning of the list, so they'll be found quickest.

Comment: Another option is to use a tree structure instead of a list. So you start with the range `0 - 999.99`, and within that you'll have `0 - 99.99`, `100-199.0`, etc.

Comment: You use a recursive procedure to find the tier within the tree.